# How to show 24 hour time picker in tempusdominus plugin

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using this plugin https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/

to insert a datetimepicker. I would display time picker showing time in 24 hours (i.e not showing 02:00 PM but 14:00).
There a way to perform this, with tempusdominus plugin. I follow the guide, but it still display time with AM and PM.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your jQuery you should set format from LT to

```
format:'HH:mm';
```

If you want the date and time just set

```
 format: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm';
```

You can find all your formats at [Formats](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Comment: Thanks, it was as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I changed the code to:

```
    $('.datePicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm',
    });
```

and it works now